# How do I find the last day of EVERY month for a full year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that has rows for each of the next 365 days (starting today). The first column has the date incrementing from today to the next 365 days and the remaining columns are blank. In one of the blank columns I want to look at the date value in column 1 and if it is a "last day of the month" add a value to that row from a different dataset. The following code works for the last day of the current month but the rest of them no...

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!THEDATE.Value, (DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)), Fields!lot_size.Value, "END_OF_MONTH")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the next day from this one and if the months are different, then the date is the last day of the month:

```
=IIF(Month(Fields!THEDATE.Value) <> Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Fields!THEDATE.Value)), 
    LOOKUP(Fields!THEDATE.Value, Fields!THEDATE.Value, Fields!lot_size.Value, "END_OF_MONTH"),
    Nothing)
```

Based on the comments, there is nothing to look up so the `lot_size` can just be accessed with `FIRST` like so:

```
=IIF(Month(Fields!THEDATE.Value) <> Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Fields!THEDATE.Value)), 
    FIRST(Fields!lot_size.Value, "END_OF_MONTH"), 
    Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesnt quite work. The LOOKUP isn't referencing a matching "THEDATE" field. I just need THEDATE to be verified as a last day of the month in the current report and then if it is...it pulls a number (lot_size) from a different dataset. Lot_size is the ONLY value - a single number. So in text form the statement should be - If the value in THEDATE is a last day of the month, add the value of lot_size to column 2 next to that date. Again it a single value and should only appear on rows that have a "last day of the month".

Comment: To be specific....the statement fails on the second THEDATE value in the LOOKUP part. =IIF(Month(Fields!THEDATE.Value) <> Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Fields!THEDATE.Value)), 
    LOOKUP(Fields!THEDATE.Value, **Fields!THEDATE.Value**, Fields!lot_size.Value, "END_OF_MONTH"),
    Nothing).                         There is no THEDATE field in the END_OF_MONTH dataset. It has only one value - lot_size.

Comment: What are you looking up by in the END_OF_MONTH dastaset then? If there is just one field, then there is nothing to look up - you can just use `FIRST` like so: `=IIF(Month(Fields!THEDATE.Value) <> Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Fields!THEDATE.Value)), FIRST(Fields!lot_size.Value, "END_OF_MONTH"), Nothing)`

Comment: That worked!! Thank you! I wasnt doing any comparison with the LOOKUP. I think I just got off track because it worked initially using a LOOKUP but only for the current month. Obviously im not adept at coding...so thank you for your patience!!